# React test if component contains another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, react-testing-library

I have loading page:

```
const Loading: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
    return (
        <div className="w-screen h-screen overflow-hidden">
            <LoadingBackground />
        </div>
    );
};
```

How can I test if `LoadingBackground` is rendered or not?

```
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import Loading from "./Loading";
import LoadingBackground from "../../components/LoadingBackground";

test("Loading", () => {
        const parent = render(<Loading />);
        expect(parent).toContainElement(loadingBackground); <-- Check if LoadingBackground is rendered or not?
});
```

Comment: What is `<LoadingBackground>`? Is there a way to identify it in your DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add something to `LoadingBackground` that can be used to identify it. If you don't have any unique text or so, you can add `data-testid={'loadingBackground'}` as an attribute to your element and do something like this:

```
within(parent).getByTestId('loadingBackground')
```